FileFallocate error on Postgresql 16
we have a large database upgraded to PostgreSQL version 16.2 (RHEL 8.9 - ppcl64).
When we process new data packages in the database, this error randomly appears:
could not extend file "pg_tblspc/16401/PG_16_202307071/17820/<file_name>" with FileFallocate(): No space left on device
The error appears completely randomly. And that when processing both large and small data packages.
When an error is detected, the process is restarted and the processing is successful.
A small package is processed in seconds to minutes. A large package can take up to several hours to process.

For example:
A small package was processed for 0.2 seconds and then the error occurred. After restarting the process it was processing for 0.4 seconds and finished fine.
One large package was processing for 2.5 hours and the error occurred. After restarting the process it processed for 4 hours and then finished fine.

This did not appear on the previous version of Posgres (13.5).
The database size is approximately 70 TB, with 26 TB available on the disk.
Database is on one huge tablespace. There are about 50 schemas and in each schema there are dozens of tables.
Does anyone have any idea what this could be and how to fix it?
Thanks,
Michal

Do you have 1 huge table in your db? You say When we process new data packages in the database - do you mean data packets - i.e incoming data?

I updated my question about the database structure.

Ok - great, but what are both large and small data packages.?

A small package is processed in seconds to minutes. A large package can take up to several hours to process.

In which kind of filesystem does the tablespace stand ? (xfs, ext4 ?)

Can you also describe the operation you're performing on data at SQL level ? Is that insert, update commands or copy (or anything else)?

On the server is xfs .

Do you use the option --clone from pg_upgrade to upgrade from PG 13.5 to 16.2 ?
